# Couldn't understand the working of Kth smallest element in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, search, vector

[image]

Code snippet function to find the kth smallest element in an array

```cpp
{
    vector <int> ans(arr, arr+r+1);

    sort(ans.begin(), ans.end());

    return ans[k-1];
}
```

I am unable to understand the working of this code, please explain

Comment: take a look at std::min_element as an alternative to sorting.

Answer (score 0):

The shown code does the following.

1. It defines a variable with the name "ans" of type `std::vector`. In C++ people usually do not use C-Style arrays but more so called *container*, like `std::vector` or `std::array`. The feature-set of such containers is much better than that of plain C-style arrays
2. In C++ you can use so called "constructor"s which may initialize classes with values.
3. The `std::vector` has many constructors, one of them is the [range constructor (5)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). This will copy a range of values, from the begin of an area to the end of an area into the vector
4. So, in your case, r+1 values from the C-style array will be copied into the vector.
5. With `sort(ans.begin(), ans.end());` the values in the `std::vector` will be sorted in ascending sequence.
6. Since the values are sorted, the smallest values will be at the beginning.
7. Caveat. The indices for array-like types in CPP start with index 0. Hence you see `k-1`

Example: If you want to have the 3rd smalles value, then k=3. And the value with index `k-1`, so, 2, will be accessed

Having orignal array with values 5,4,3,2,1, after the sorting we will have 1,2,3,4,5 with

```
Index:  0   Value 1
Index:  1   Value 2
Index:  2   Value 3
Index:  3   Value 4
Index:  4   Value 5
```

So, selecting value at index 2, will give you the expected result 3.